# Terminal does not appear in "open with" program list

Tags: gnome-terminal

[image: open with list]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling gnome-terminal and installing Konsole, neither appear as an option to open programs with.

I'm trying to run a .sh shell.

Edit: Yes, I had selected to allow code execution already.

Comment: Did you make the file executable? (Right Mouseclick on the file -> `Preferences` -> `Permission`-tab -> check `Allow executing file as program`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Unity & Gnome, similar things are there for other desktop environments *(for KDE's dolphin file manager, I think you can set what you want it to do by right-clicking on the executable file and selecting **'Open With...'** > **'Other'**)*

Right click on the file, and go to <kbd>Properties</kbd>, and permissions. Make sure this is ticked :

[image: Execute - TICK Allow executing file as program] 
<sup>*(You need this ticked anyway for the file to run in terminal, or be 'executed', it is the same as running `chmod +x /PATH/TO/FILE`)*</sup>

And make sure this,  under the <kbd>Behaviour</kbd> tab, in Nautilus file manager's preferences, is set to this:
[image: Executable Text Files - Ask Each Time]

Now every time you click on it, you should get this, which will work much the same as the right-click menu:

[image: Do you want to run EXAMPLE.py, or show its contents - buttons]

<kbd>Run in Terminal</kbd>, you can guess.
 <kbd>Display</kbd> opens it in the default text editor defined in 'Open With...'. in the files preferences.
 <kbd>Run</kbd> runs it in the background, with no terminal. This is also what happens if you select 'Run executable text files when they are opened' above.

Also, here is a fix to stop `gnome-terminal` closing instantly once the script has completed - go to <kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd>,  and under <kbd>Title and Command</kbd>, set:

[image: 'When the command exits' to 'Hold the terminal open'], Now when you run a script like this (works the same for shell scripts):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
print "Hello"
time.sleep(5)
print "Goodbye"
```

<sup>*(Remember the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` line, otherwise it won't be interpreted correctly. You can also use `#!/usr/bin/env python` - for shell scripts `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`)*</sup>

It stay open a while, then you should get something like:
[image]

---

**To (attempt) to get Terminal to appear in the right-click menu:**
I have tried the following adding this to `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` under `[Added Associations]`:

```
text/x-shellscript=gnome-terminal.desktop
application/x-shellscript=gnome-terminal.desktop
```

Also I have tried adding this to `gnome-terminal`'s launcher file (`/usr/share/applications`)

```
NoDisplay=false
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;
```

Neither of which seemed to work - but setting it so you can click on the File and select 'Open in Terminal' is an ideal substitute.

Comment: Thanks, the Nautalis executable text files behaviour setting was the problem. I'm not sure how that got changed as I didn't even know it existed.